# JOIN different tables

Tags: mysql

I need to solve a problem about joining tables based on fields.
I have 3 tables:

```sql
NEWS (id,title)

COMMENTS (id,idtopic,message)

NOTIFICATIONS (iduser,idnews,idtopic,idpost)
```

When `COMMENTS` has `idtopic=0` then it's a topic, when it's >0 then it's a topic's reply.
By `NOTIFICATIONS` users are informed about each kind of informations.

Now I would like to get fields from other tables, selecting `NOTIFICATIONS`.

The base `SELECT` is:

```sql
SELECT idnews,idtopic,idpost FROM notifications WHERE iduser=X
```

Now i would like to JOIN:

- NEWS->title, if idnews>0
- COMMENTS->message, if idtopic>0
- COMMENTS->message, if idpost>0

I suppose I should make something like this:

```sql
SELECT CASE idnews>0 THEN ??,
       CASE idtopic>0 THEN ??, CASE idpost>0 THEN
  FROM NOTIFICATIONS
```

and I would like to return always a field with title or message, because one of idnews/idtopic/idpost is ALWAYS >0

How to SELECT inside SELECT without joining each tables on each record? I don't want to make

```sql
SELECT *
 FROM NOTIFICATIONS
 LEFT JOIN NEWS ON NOTIFICATIONS.idnews=NEWS.id
 LEFT JOIN COMMENTS ON NOTIFICATIONS.idtopic=COMMENTS.id
 LEFT JOIN COMMENTS ON NOTIFICATIONS.idpost=COMMENTS.id
```

because performances would be worse than to `CASE WHEN idnews>0 OR idtopic>0 OR idpost>0`.

Comment: Do you think it's better JOIN three tables instead to CASE SELECT based on the field>0?

Comment: I need to return a field with title or message, based on the type of field (idnews/idtopic/idpost) >0

Comment: if idnews is the id of news, idtopic is the id of comment, what is idpost?

Comment: When COMMENTS has idtopic=0 then it's a topic, when it's >0 then it's a topic's reply.
On NOTIFICATIONS, idtopic is the id of topic, idpost is the id of a post. I know, they are on the same table and the field is the same, but i need to split them on NOTIFICATIONS to identify categories of messages

Comment: it seems that norification will hold duplicate info for idpost and idtopic

Comment: there won't be any duplicates if i can choose the right join based on the only one field >0

Comment: And i can't redesign the schema cause i'm already online (http://www.ilbardelfumetto.com)

Comment: so just to make clear, only one of idtopic or idpost will be greater than 0 all the time in notification table?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what your asking, but, you can select inside a select like this...

```
SELECT donor.idno, name, contamt, driveno 
FROM donor, donation 
WHERE donor.idno = donation.idno AND driveno > any 
(SELECT driveno FROM drive WHERE drivename = 'Animal Home');
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly, try this:

```
create procedure printNotification(in input_userid int)
BEGIN
  DECLARE id_news int;
  DECLARE id_topic int;
  DECLARE id_post int;
  DECLARE id_title char(30);
  DECLARE id_message char(30);
  SELECT idnews,idtopic,idpost INTO @id_news,@id_topic,@id_post FROM NOTIFICATIONS WHERE iduser=input_userid;
  IF(id_news>0) THEN
    SELECT title INTO @id_title FROM NEWS WHERE id=id_news;
  END IF;

  IF(id_topic>0) THEN
    SELECT message INTO @id_message FROM COMMENTS WHERE id=idtopic;
  END IF;

  IF(idpost>0) THEN
    SELECT message INTO @id_message FROM COMMENTS WHERE id=idpost;
  END IF;

END//
```